# How to make Protractor repeat the implementation of multiple test cases?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am making an AngularJS app with Protractor e2e test tool.
I want to make the e2e test run for a  long time. Constantly log in, click， write, log off, then repeat. Which protractor api I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop your it block. Simple for each loop would work